# How to keep my app from getting flagged by windows 10?

Tags: windows, security, windows-10, exe, virus

I've made an application exe for my personal business, but when clients download it and run it on windows 10 specifically, it is flagged as potentially dangerous. I am new to software. Is there a workaround for this or a way to register my application with windows for this?

I've tried googling solutions of course. A lot of nonrelated security stuff is all I can find on this subject. Or how to get around this as a user. I would like my clients to not feel like they're downloading a virus.

Answer (score 0):

Your executable file needs to be signed.

See [Use code signing for added control and protection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/use-code-signing-to-simplify-application-control-for-classic-windows-applications).